# How to expect void method call with any argument using EasyMock

Tags: unit-testing, junit, easymock

As a part of unit test I need to mock a void function(Which accept any non-primitive paramter. e.g. MAP) call with any argument.

```
mockObj.myMethod(<anyObject>)
```

Is it possible to do this with EasyMock?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use either of the `anyObject` methods: [anyObject()](http://www.easymock.org/api/easymock/3.1/org/easymock/EasyMock.html#anyObject%28%29) or [anyObject(T)](http://www.easymock.org/api/easymock/3.1/org/easymock/EasyMock.html#anyObject%28java.lang.Class%29)

So

```
 expect(mockObj.myMethod(anyObject()));
```

See the **Flexible Expectations with Argument Matchers** section of the [documentation](http://www.easymock.org/EasyMock3_1_Documentation.html)

Comment: updated link: http://easymock.org/user-guide.html#verification-expectations

Comment: void methods now use expectLastCall() in EasyMock I believe, as for how to capture the argument , I don't know