# EasyMock how to capture argument of a void method called by method under test?

Tags: java, mocking, easymock

From the documentation, my understanding is that expectLastCall() is to be used for void methods, not expect(), accordingly I get a complaint in Eclipse when doing so.

```
Capture<String> capturedArgument = new Capture<>();
expect(testObject.voidMethodName(capture(capturedArgument)));
```

This [How to expect void method call with any argument using EasyMock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123993/how-to-expect-void-method-call-with-any-argument-using-easymock) doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TestClass testObj = new TestClass();

Capture<String> capturedArgument = new Capture<>(); //change type as needed
testObj.voidMethodName(capture(capturedArgument));
expectLastCall().atLeastOnce();//adjust number of times as needed
//may need additional replay if you have an additional mocks control object
replay(testObj);

testObj.methodUnderTest();
```

Comment: why would you need a partial mock for that?!?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to call the void method to record it.

```
Capture<String> capturedArgument = new Capture<>();
testObject.voidMethodName(capture(capturedArgument));
replay(testObject);
```

That's it. This implicitly means you expect the void method to be called once. Adding `expectLastCall().once();` or `expectLastCall();` means the exact same thing and is useless.

You can't call `expect()` since a void method doesn't return anything. So you can't pass it in parameter to `expect()`.

You might wonder why `expectLastCall()` exists then. For two reasons:

1. For special "returns" like `expectLastCall().andThrow(e)`
2. To record a specific number of calls like `expectLastCall().atLeastOnce()`